# Task scheduler - run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I am trying to run task scheduler on my local pc (windows 10), I have set it up to run a exe file stored on my C drive daily, but it doesn't run when I set it to "run whether user is logged on or not".

It works fine when set to "Run only when user is logged on", but I need it to run when I am not logged on.

Currently, if I press run it instantly stops running and says "ready" but nothing has been executed. the last run result is 0x0

Any ideas on what could fix this?

Actions is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9OSM.png)

General is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le5PR.png)

History is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvlDv.png)

Settings is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOgeN.png)

Triggers is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZjIm.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: logon as batch permission has to be granted for the user in secpol.msc . Also the correct password must be entered in the task properties

Comment: @DavidTrevor thank you for your comment, the account I am using has logon as batch permissions, and in regards to passwords I can confirm the password is correct.

Comment: not sure what your .exe is doing, it might operate in a way that expects a logged on user session? And simply terminates if called from task scheduler. Explaining the 0x0 success error code

Comment: The .exe is a PowerShell execute (ps1) that I converted to an exe. Pretty much all it does is pull stats from exchange.  I have tried with a simple command like "write-host" and even that doesn't work.

Comment: The event history in task scheduler should have events that provide more information.

Comment: Unfortunately not, all I am getting is task completed successfully, but that is not the case. - I have updated my question to show this. 

Is it okay for the exe doc to be on the C: drive or does it need to be located somewhere else maybe?

Comment: Please provide some information by running some PowerShell commands: # Replace 'TaskName' with the name of the scheduled task $TaskName = 'YourScheduledTaskName' # Get the task's name, state, and last run time $TaskInfo = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName | Select-Object TaskName, State, LastRunTime # Get the task's triggers $Triggers = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Triggers # Get the task's actions $Actions = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Actions # Get the task's settings $Settings = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskNam

Comment: I have added the required screenshots to my original questions,

Comment: The screenshots doesn't provide enough information, that's why included a basic troubleshooting steps, to check the logs. And the benefit of PowerShell command output is that you can copy/paste it, that much easier for us.

Comment: Does the user has enough permissions on the ACL to read that exe? Has your accounts the rights to logon non-interactively in the local security policy?

Comment: Yeah it has all the required permissions

Comment: I will give it another try i keep getting The term 'Get-ScheduledTaskLog' is not recognized

Update - just tested again and same output

Comment: Check Task History Settings:

First, ensure that task history is enabled for the specific tasks you want to monitor. Follow these steps:

Open "Task Scheduler" from the Start menu or by searching for it.
In the left pane, navigate to "Task Scheduler Library."
In the middle pane, select the task for which you want to enable history.
In the right pane, under the "Actions" section, click on "Properties."
In the task properties window, go to the "Settings" tab.Ensure that the "Enable" option under "History" is checked.Repeat this process for each task for which you want to enable history.

Comment: Thanks not sure that's the problem as you can see by my screenshot history is enabled

Comment: I would suggest to just try run that powershell script from the task to see if that works. Microsoft might now allow running other shells for powershell scripts (it could be blocked and seen as obfuscation, a technique used with malware)

Comment: I have a feeling we are slightly leading astray from the actual problem, see it works completely fine for when  set to "user is logged on" but not with "whether user is logged on or not" is there any reason the task cant see the exe?

Comment: Then you need check non interactive logon as I said before  in the local gpo, or run it under a local admin account, or an account who is member of the local admins.

Comment: I have done that and still no luck

Comment: Have you checked the windows event logs if you any errors there?

Comment: Run the PS1 way with Task Scheduler and take the exe out of the loop. This is 100% possible. You can pass sensitive strings in as `$arg[#]` in the PS script with the Task Scheduler settings. Having the sensitive strings even in the exe is not secure if that's the reason you are making a PS1 into an exe (security by obscurity) only adds a little bit of protection. Make it run as a restricted about with explicit security to only what it needs, if the password, etc. is gotten, no-admin level things can occur, etc. type deal. All trivial, what are you trying to accomplish exactly and why exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the script output anything? It won't show anything to a shell if it's running non-interactively and will terminate immediately. If there is no exit code returned task scheduler will assume it ran successfully (exit code 0).

Add some verbosity to see which step in the task is failing.

E.g. $Data | Out-File C:\Temp\Data.log

If Data.log is blank then it failed to pull the data, then your problem is isolated to access/privileges to exchange and the task runs fine.

I saw it stated the password is fine, I'm assuming that means you checked the security event logs and saw a successful authentication and access to the resources though.